# Installing Git on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, git, github, msysgit

I've installed several different versions of Git on Windows all with the same failure.  I get an error "libssh2.dll is not installed on this computer...".

I looked around the installation files, and, Windows is right, it's not there.  I've tried installing the ssh2.dll binaries (the only place I could find them is in a php distribution), putting them in the system directories and everything.

Does anyone know the source of / or a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this.  I can't say exactly what the source of the problem all along has been - in other words, why it hasn't worked with various git installations, etc.  Though I expect the problem was the same; it doesn't make sense that I kept installing different  broken Git packages.

At any rate, what solved it is this:

I had downloaded the `libssh2.dll` binaries from the libssh2.org website, but the file that came with it was `libssh2-1.dll`, which went undetected by git.  It didn't occur to me rename it, but that might've worked.

However, what **did** work was downloading the [Cgminer binaries](https://github.com/kanoi/cgminer-binaries/blob/master/4.1.0/cgminer-4.1.0-windows.zip), which - as I somehow discovered - happen to contain `libssh2.dll`.

I then copied `libssh2.dll` into `..\mysisgit\bin`, and git has worked perfectly since.  God knows why it wasn't there; especially since this is the version of mysisgit that is packaged with `cmder` (thus I assume it is a recent mysisgit version).

This has driven me stupid.  Notice the date of my original post.

Answer (score 3):

That [bug was fixed in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6774629/6309).

I would recommend, as an installation process, to simply unzip a [portable version of msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount).

```
PortableGit-1.8.3-preview20130601.7z
```

There won't be an issue then.

Comment: This is a good answer I guess. People like it.  I cannot resolve this problem on two different computers.  Maybe I am handicapped.